# Maverick MVC on IIS7.5 - Handler mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

We've a legacy (very legacy!) app that uses Maverick.net: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mavnet/

This works fine on IIS6, however we are now migrating it to iis7.5, which should be fairly easy but isn't working for us. We've configured the app pool to use .net framework v2.0 in classic mode to emulate iis6.

We have the following in the web.config

```
        <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.m" type="Maverick.Dispatcher, Maverick" />
    </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
        <add name="Maverick" path="*.m" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And in IIS7.5 for this application I have the following Script handler mapping configured

- Request Path: *.m
- Executable:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll // as
  per maverick documentation
- Name: Maverick

Request Restrictions

- Invoke Handler if request is mapped to: File or folder
- Verbs: All verbs
- Access: Execute

The maverick.config file reads as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><maverick version="2.0" default-view-type="document" default-transform-type="document">
<commands>

    <command name="welcome"> <!--Entry page-->
        <controller class="PAPI.Controllers.StoreDetails, PAPI"/>
        <view name="login" path="login.aspx" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="help" path="help.aspx" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="error" path="error.aspx" type="redirect"/> 
    </command>

    <command name="setPrincipal"> <!--Sets the security-->
        <controller class="PAPI.Controllers.SetPrincipal, PAPI"/>
        <view name="login" path="login.aspx" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="success" path="instructions.m" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="error" path="error.aspx" type="redirect"/> 
    </command>  

    <command name="instructions"> <!--Controller for instruction pages-->
        <controller class="PAPI.Controllers.GetNextPage, PAPI"/>
        <view name="login" path="login.aspx?" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="dataProtection" path="dataprotection.aspx" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="instructions1" path="instructions1.aspx?" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="example" path="example.aspx?" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="instructions2" path="instructions2.aspx?" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="questionnaire" path="questionnaire.aspx?" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="finished" path="finished.aspx?" type="redirect"/>
        <view name="error" path="error.aspx" type="redirect"/> 
    </command>

</commands>
```

Which is the same as IIS6 afaik. Yet it doesn't work on iis7.5. When a page is request, e.g. http://localhost/app/login.aspx, it maps to http://localhost/app/welcome.m which then returns a 404. The log files shows 302 redirects to welcome.m and then IIS doens't know what to do with it, so the config must be wrong.

We've tried using a module mapping instead of a script mapping but the same problem occurs.

Does anybody have any ideas as to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my colleague solved this by adding 2 module mappings configured to use IsapiModule instead of script mappings. One for 32 bit pointing to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll and one for 64 bit pointing to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll.

Just in case anybody runs into this in future.